# Using Playwright with CSS that contains nth element

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to find an element with a specific nth index as a CSS expression.

How can I fix my code **without changing** the CSS expression?

```
try:
    expect(self.page.locator('div[class="some-class"]:nth(3)')).\
                   to_be_visible(timeout=20000)
    return True
except AssertionError:
    return False
```

The error I get is:

{Error}DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'div[class="some-class"]:nth(3)' is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locator should look like this. Replace ":" with ">>"

```css
div[class="some-class"]>>nth=3
```

Comment: How can I solve my issue without changing the CSS expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```py
self.page.locator('div.some-class').nth(3)
//or
self.page.locator('div.some-class').nth(4)
```